# PHP Session only stores one value

Tags: php, postgresql, session

```
function StoreUserProfileInSession( $username, $password )
{
        session_start();
        $query = pg_query( "SELECT * FROM mytable where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'" );

        $rows = pg_fetch_array( $query );

        foreach( $rows as $key => $value )
        {
            if( $key == 'password' ) //do not store password in session because it's DANGEROUS!
                continue;

            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
}
```

After this function is being called i am redirected to my frontend.
When I try to `print_r($_SESSION);` in there I only got a one value in session, and that is the user_id, I have many fields in my table.
Why am I only getting one value? what's wrong with this?

Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!
Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you remember to `session_start()` in the request that you are calling this function?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: There's a `session_start()` at the top of the function, shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: Yes i added a session_start() in my frontend.

Comment: @mu ah yes missed that out. thanks!

Comment: well @elson, it's more recommended that you put all this in a bootstrap file where you can manage across your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. `pg_fetch_array()` is not returning what you expect.
2. `$_SESSION` **cannot have any key name that could not also be a php variable name**.

`$rows` looks like this:

```
$rows = array(
    'user_id' => 1
    1,
    'password' => 'THE PASSWORD',
    'THE PASSWORD',
);
$rows['user_id'] === $rows[0];
// etc
```

Thus in your foreach loop, right after the `user_id` key, you are actually doing this:

```
$_SESSION[0] = 1;
```

This is illegal, so the session object stops working.

Instead do this:

```
// PGSQL_ASSOC says, "only return named keys, not numeric keys"
$therow = pg_fetch_array($query, null, PGSQL_ASSOC);
unset($therow['password']);
$_SESSION['user'] = $therow;
pg_free_result($query);


// get user data like this:
$_SESSION['user']['user_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps is this because you're only getting one row after you execute your query?

How many rows are returned by:

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. I managed to answer it by doing this one.

```
function StoreUserProfileInSession( $username, $password )
    {
        session_start();
        $query = pg_query( "SELECT * FROM mytable where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'" );
        $fields = array();

        while( $rows = pg_fetch_array( $query ) )
        {
            $fields[] = $rows;
        }

        foreach( $fields[0] as $key => $value )
        {
            if( is_int( $key ) || $key == 'password' )
                continue;
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is both bad style and dangerous. It is bad style because you pollute the `$_SESSION` namespace--a two-level hierarchy would be better. It is **dangerous** because you could conceivably have a table column name which is not also a valid php variable name. In this situation your application would *silently break*!

Comment: Can you share me a table name who is at the same time an invalid variable name.

Thanks! :)

Comment: The php T_VARIABLE token must match this regex: [`[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), whereas an SQL quoted identifier [can contain almost anything](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Here's some easy examples: "my column", "1tablename", "@attr", etc.